# What does "Using sort_union" mean?

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

(Not sure is this has been discussed before ...)

When building SQL for category

example category data:

```
ID | NAME
--------------------------
1  | hardware
2  | hardware : notebooks
3  | hardware : phones
4  | hardware : desktops
5  | review
6  | review : photo gallery
```

`hardware` will be the parent category for `hardware : *`

When I considering building api to query database

```
desc select * from category 
where id=1 or 
name like concat((select name from category where id in(1)), '_%');
```

the above return (in the execution plan)

```
Using sort_union(PRIMARY,some_index); Using where
```

What is the `sort_union` means ?
Good ? Bad? To be avoid ?

---

(understand I could rewrite the entire query into a more optimize way,
but there are some constraints for me to re-build the entire api)

---

mysql version 5.1

Comment: I think this is certainly not a bad thing, since it can make the query extremely faster. Personally, I had a situation where I forgot to create an index on one column in a certain table. When the records were scarce at the beginning, I couldn't even feel the difference. But once it exceeded 3.5 million, it started to be felt when the query took 200 ms for a full table scan. After adding the index, sort_union started to execute the query in 0.0009 s, instead of 0.2427 s. And app started to run as fast as at the beginning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sort_union is used when you have a where clause in which you are OR'ing two or more, for which MySQL thinks it's better than using index_merge.

For more information, [see the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-merge-sort-union.html)

In short, it's not bad (imho); since it will fetch the rows from both indexes first, before sort-unioning them.

Comment: nice, forget to mention ... the DB is running at version 5.1

Comment: @ajreal Luckily; that feature was the same in 5.1 :) [5.1 doc page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-merge-optimization.html#index-merge-sort-union)